# text file into a dynamic array of structures C programing

Tags: c, text-files, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I have a text file with this information

```
 AreaA  500 2   
 AreaB  200 1       
 AreaC  100 2   
 AreaD  1000    1
```

and I want to put read this information into a dynamic array of structures
I made this struct

```
  typedef struct dadosZoo zoo, *pZoo;
  struct dadosZoo {
     char AreaID[ID_TAM];
     int capacidade;
     int adjacentes;
     //areas adjacentes
  };
```

and then i created a function 'area_Estrutura' which was supposed to read the file and put the information into a dynamic array of structures.

```
 void area_Estrutura(char *nomeFich, zoo *z){
    FILE *f;
    /* int cap, adj;
    char areId;*/
    //zoo *z;

    f = fopen(nomeFich, "r");
    if (f ==NULL){
       printf("Erro na abertura do ficheiro %s para leitura.\n", nomeFich);
       return;
    }

    while(fscanf(f, "%c\t%d\t%d\n", &z->AreaID, &z->capacidade, &z->adjacentes)!=EOF){
        z = malloc(sizeof(zoo));
        if(z!=NULL){
           fscanf(f, "%c\t%d\t%d\n", &z->AreaID, &z->capacidade, &z->adjacentes);
           fprintf(f, "%s\t%d\t%d\n", z->AreaID, z->capacidade, z->adjacentes);
           free(z);
        }

     }
 fclose(f);

}
```

I never know how many structures but one line is one structure so I did this

```
 while(fscanf(f, "%c\t%d\t%d\n", &z->AreaID, &z->capacidade, &z->adjacentes)!=EOF)
```

that reads the file while not end of the file in this line i don't know if i should read it like that or with the variables that i created up there

```
 char areId;
 int cap, adj;
```

then in the main i put this call to function

```
   zoo *zoo;
   area_Estrutura("Zoo.txt", zoo);
```

and i wanted it to print on the screen. when i build the code i don't have any mistakes or warnings but it doesn't run. Does someone have any idea.
Sorry if the formatation or the english is a little bit confusing but it is not my mother toungue, thank you.

Comment: Please define "doesn't run". Does it crash? Does it produce the wrong result? etc? Also, please don't present the code like telling a story. It is more useful to provide a single block of code as a [mcve] that reproduces the problem as that will give the full picture.

Comment: yes, it crashes.

Comment: @xing i tried this format `fscanf(f, "%s\t%d\t%d\n", &areId, &cap, &adj)` for both scanfs and it does run but it doesn't printf but because of the fprintf shouldn't be printing in the console?

Comment: @xing okay i am a loser fprintf is not for console but for the file. Now i changed that but i'm doing it right am i putting the file information into a dynamic array of structures

Comment: @xing yeah you are right it's printing the second and fourth lines of the file, what should I do?

Comment: @xing just to try it out i put that `z = malloc(10*sizeof(zoo));` and made a for `for(int i =0 ; i< 10; i++)`  and did this `fscanf(f, "%s%d%d", &z[i].AreaID, &z[i].capacidade, &z[i].adjacentes);`   and the same with the printf and it prints the second, third and fourth lines and 7 more lines of garbage...

Comment: It is almost always a mistake to place a whitespace character at the end of a `scanf()` format string. This probably does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change 
fscanf(f, "%c\t%d\t%d\n", &z->AreaID, &z->capacidade, &z->adjacentes)
to
fscanf(f, "%s\t%d\t%d\n", z->AreaID, &z->capacidade, &z->adjacentes)

ie %c to %s and do not pass address of areadID

Comment: Trailing whitespace characters in a `scanf()` format string are almost always a mistake.